# Best Video Options(s) for Mobile phone devices

Tags: mobile, video, native

If I have a video of 100 frames what would be the best format for native mobile applications?

If the answer is each make (ie Android, iPhone, Blackberry etc) is different should i consider using a series of jpeg images displayed via a timer instead?

Thanks

Comment: `3gp` is an option that's been around for a decade. Should be pretty cross-compatible.

Comment: Hi, i shall take a look at that format now.Thanks